# SSH port fowarding on Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, port-forwarding, airport

I am trying to access a VM that I have on a server on a local network run by an Apple Airport Extreme 2nd gen from outside the network via SSH. I have set up SSH port forwarding on the airport extreme already. On Ubuntu I run the following command to connect to the VM on airport network:

```
sudo ssh -L 22:local IP of VM:22 AirportIP
```

I then get prompted for the root password of the router. I tried setting a username and a password and hostname for the router by checking the option of "Dynamic global host name". I have also tried:

```
sudo ssh -L 22:local IP of VM:22 username@AirportIP (and also) hostname@AirportIP
```

None of these work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to login to the airport, or how to find out the correct login and password? In addition, are there better ways to access the VM GUI and not just the terminal via port fowarding? (not necessarily ssh and not VNC)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AirPort Extreme doesn't run `sshd`. You don't need its password. The port mapping you set up means it will just blindly forward the packets on the specified public port, to the private LAN IP address and port you also specified in the port mapping. The base station has no idea that the traffic it's forwarding happens to be `ssh`.

You should just `ssh` normally to the public (WAN) IP address of the AirPort Extreme, and it will forward your connection attempt to the private LAN host that you'd set up the port mapping to point to.

```
ssh VMUserName@AirPortPublicWANIP
```

(This assumes that when you set up the port mapping, you pointed the ssh port, port 22, to whatever port sshd is listening to on your private LAN host. If you specified a different port number, then specify it in your `ssh` command.)

When prompted for a password, even though SSH will probably think it's asking you for the password for AirPortPublicWANIP, **YOU** should know that you're really talking to your VM, so enter the password for whichever account you were trying to log into in the VM.

If you've specifically been using port 20 instead of 22, consider using some other alternate port. The base station's NAT gateway code contains special code called an "Application Layer Gateway" (ALG) to handle FTP traffic, and FTP uses ports 21 and 20. So there's some chance you might be running afoul of the FTP ALG if you use those ports.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I was using port 22 with the airport and in my actual command. I accidentally wrote port 20 here. Also do have any suggestions for other protocols to use to access the Linux VM GUI from a windows or other linux machine? I have Xming on my computer, and In addition, I know VNC is laggy and not secure.I was wondering if there is something better than these. Thank you